# IOS Core-Plot: How to get visible range of X and Y axis

Tags: ios, core-plot

In Core-Plot I want to plot only the visible area of the plot. For this I need the visible range of the  plot after Zoom-In and Zoom-Out.

Any Idea how to get visible range of X-Axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a plot space delegate to find out when the plot ranges change. Each delegate method receives a reference to the plot space as one of its parameters. You can read the `xRange` and `yRange` to find out what the new ranges are.

Answer (score 0):

You can get visible range of X-Axis using code like this:
`space.graph.axisSet.xAxis.visibleAxisRange`